# Why is my Fiddle struct being filled with garbage?

Tags: ruby, winapi, fiddle, ruby-ffi

I'm attempting to convert a very simple C Win32 API call over to Ruby utilizing Fiddle and I'm not having much success.

The first two method calls work flawlessly, though when I get to the call which populates a struct I'm having a bit of difficulty, as it appears the struct is being populated with garbage data:

Here's the relevant C code:

```
DWORD dwHandle, dwLen;
LPVOID lpData;
UINT BufLen;
VS_FIXEDFILEINFO *pFileInfo;
LPTSTR LibName = L"C:\\windows\\notepad.exe";

dwLen = GetFileVersionInfoSize(LibName, &dwHandle);

if(dwLen != 0) 
{
    lpData = malloc(dwLen);

    if (GetFileVersionInfo(LibName, NULL, &dwLen, lpData)) 
    {
        if (VerQueryValue(lpData, L"\\", (LPVOID)&pFileInfo, (PUINT)&BufLen))
        {
                printf("ProductVersion: %d.%d.%d.%d\n", HIWORD(pFileInfo->dwProductVersionMS), LOWORD(pFileInfo->dwProductVersionLS), HIWORD(pFileInfo->dwFileVersionLS), LOWORD(pFileInfo->dwFileVersionLS));
                printf("FileVersion: %d.%d.%d.%d\n", HIWORD(pFileInfo->dwFileVersionMS), LOWORD(pFileInfo->dwFileVersionMS), HIWORD(pFileInfo->dwFileVersionLS), LOWORD(pFileInfo->dwFileVersionLS));
        }
    }
}
```

And here's my attempt at converting the C to Ruby:

```
require 'fiddle/import'

module Version
    extend Fiddle::Importer
    dlload 'version'
    typealias 'HANDLE', 'void*'
    typealias 'LPVOID', 'void*'
    typealias 'LPCVOID', 'const void*'
    typealias 'LPDWORD', 'int*'
    typealias 'HWND', 'HANDLE'
    typealias 'LPCSTR', 'const char*'
    typealias 'LPCWSTR', 'const wchar_t*'
    typealias 'UINT', 'unsigned int'
    typealias 'PUINT', 'unsigned int*'
    typealias 'DWORD', 'unsigned long'
    typealias 'BOOL', 'int'
    extern 'DWORD GetFileVersionInfoSize(LPCSTR, LPDWORD)'
    extern 'BOOL GetFileVersionInfo(LPCSTR, DWORD, DWORD, LPVOID)'
    extern 'BOOL VerQueryValue(LPCVOID, LPCSTR, LPVOID, PUINT)'
    VS_FIXEDFILEINFO = struct [
      'DWORD dwSignature',
      'DWORD dwStrucVersion',
      'DWORD dwFileVersionMS',
      'DWORD dwFileVersionLS',
      'DWORD dwProductVersionMS',
      'DWORD dwProductVersionLS',
      'DWORD dwFileFlagsMask',
      'DWORD dwFileFlags',
      'DWORD dwFileOS',
      'DWORD dwFileType',
      'DWORD dwFileSubtype',
      'DWORD dwFileDateMS',
      'DWORD dwFileDateLS'
    ]
end

dwHandle = Fiddle::NULL
dwLen = Version::GetFileVersionInfoSize "C:\\windows\\system32\\notepad.exe", dwHandle

lpData = Fiddle::Pointer.malloc(dwLen)
Version::GetFileVersionInfo "C:\\windows\\notepad.exe", 0, dwLen, lpData

BufLen = Fiddle::NULL
pFileInfo = Version::VS_FIXEDFILEINFO.malloc()

success = Version::VerQueryValue lpData, "\\", pFileInfo, BufLen.ref

puts "pFileInfo: #{pFileInfo.dwSignature}"
```

Unfortunately, `pFileInfo.dwSignature` appears to change every time around indicating it's being filled with garbage data (strangely enough it IS zero before the `VerQueryValue` call).  The `pFileInfo.dwSignature` value should always be `0xFEEF04BD`, or in decimal `4277077181`.

Any thoughts on what's going on here?

Thanks!

Comment: How does Fiddle handle the fact that In `winapi` there is no function called `GetFileVersionInfoSize` - instead there's `GetFileVersionInfoSizeW`  and `GetFileVersionInfoSizeA`? Your definitions seem to be assuming the ANSI version, is that correct?

Comment: This was my first thought as well, though it appears that Fiddle is handling this situation properly.  Both `GetFileVersionInfoSize` and `GetFileVersionInfo` take a LPCSTR and produce the appropriate output no issue.  On a side note, the `VerQueryValue` would fail if it received a string type it wasn't expecting.  For instance, in C, if you pass `GetFileVersionInfoSizeW` an ANSI string, then function fails and returns false.

Comment: I also wanted to add that `BufLen` is returned properly, while the struct is filled with garbage.